# how prove the following statment for this matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A:=[a_{ij}]_{n×n}$ , $a_{ij}=0$  or $a_{ij}=1$ and  $\exists m \in\mathbb N$ such that $A^m=J-I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $J=[1]_{n×n}$ (each entry is $1$). How to prove:

1. $\exists a \in\mathbb N$  such that $n=a^m+1$, and
2. $m$ is odd.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let's collaborate :) I am thinking; $\det(A^m) = \det(J-I)$. Luckily, $\det(J-I) = n-1$, when $n$ is odd and $\det(J-I) = -(n-1)$ when $n$ is even. Then, since $\det(A^m) = [\det(A)]^m$, the equation holds with $a = \det(A)$ (not sure yet as to why $m$ should be odd).

Comment: @Anon, your comment is practically an answer.

Comment: its better to write $detA^m=(-1)^n(n-1)$ then $n=\frac{{detA}^m}{(-1)^n}+1$

Comment: I love what Anon wrote, but that's full no answer yet: if I'm not missing something, $m$, so far, only need be odd if $n$ is even; and second, we need to also show that this is the only way to find such an $a$...which I'm sure you're aware of, just saying...

Comment: @DonAntonio :) Seems to be at the right track, but I still cannot see the oddness of $m$ :( Shall we look at the original A itself somehow?

Comment: @gnometorule Yeah, if $n$ is even, we are done, now to handle the odd $n$. Also, the existence of $a$ appears to be enough here.

Comment: Theorem 1 in C. W. H. Lam, J. H. van Lint, *Directed Graphs with Unique Paths of Fixed Length*, Journal of Combinatorial Theory B, vol. 24, No. 3, 1978, http://alexandria.tue.nl/repository/freearticles/593457.pdf .

Comment: @darijgrinberg aww, I just myself took the square-root $J-I$ and saw that it was imaginary :)

Comment: @Anon: you should post the full write-up as an answer so it can be accepted, which would be nice?

Comment: @gnometorule Well, I couldn't solve it completely anyway :) I guess the OP will find what he/she is looking for with complete details in the referenced paper.

Comment: this paper find solution for $A^k=-I+J $ but this paper refer  to another paper that may i find my answer in referd paper

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo Apparently, the referenced paper has a restriction on the original $A$, its diagonal elements are all-zero. I will check if it is easy to extend that result and try to write a full answer here.

Comment: I wonder: can't $\det(J-I)$ be calculated explicitly? I tested some cases in wolframalpha, and it seems that the value is $(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)$.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Note $J$ has rank $1$. The eigenvalues of $J$ are obviously $n$ (eigenvector $(1,\dots,1)^T$) and $0$ with mult. $n-1$ (the dimension of the null space). Thus $\det(xI-J)=x^{n-1}(x-n)$, and $\det(I-J)=1^{n-1}(1-n)=-(n-1)$, so $\det(J-I)=(-1)^n\det(I-J)=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(The problem statement is false when $n=1$, but we will ignore this degenerate case.) We have at least three proofs.

**Proof 1** (adapted from the proof by Anon; see his/her [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290011/how-prove-the-following-statment-for-this-matrix#comment632171_290011)). We have
$$\det (A)^m=\det (A^m)=\det(J-I)=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)$$
and therefore $n=|\det(A)|^m+1$.

**Proof 2** (adapted from Theorem 1 of C. W. H. Lam, J. H. van Lint, [*Directed Graphs with Unique Paths of Fixed Length*](http://alexandria.tue.nl/repository/freearticles/593457.pdf), Journal of Combinatorial Theory B, vol. 24, No. 3, 1978; thanks to @darij_grinberg for the [information](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290011/how-prove-the-following-statment-for-this-matrix#comment632223_290011)): $A^m=J−I$ implies that $AJ−A=A^{m+1}=JA−A$. Hence $AJ=JA$, i.e. all row sums and column sums of $A$ are equal to some natural integer $c$. Thus $AJ=JA=cJ$ and in turn $A^mJ=c^mJ$. But by property of $A$, we also have $A^mJ=(J−I)J=(n−1)J$. Therefore $c^m=n−1$.

**Proof 3**: As $2 = 1^m+1$, we may assume that $n\ge3$. Since $A$ is an entrywise nonnegative, by [Perron-Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem), the spectral radius $\rho(A)$ of $A$ is a maximal eigenvalue of $A$. Hence $\rho(A)^m$ a maximal eigenvalue of $A^m$. But when $n\ge3$, the maximal eigenvalue of $A^m=J-I$ is unique, namely $n-1$. Hence $\rho(A)^m=n-1$, or $n=\rho(A)^m+1$. Finally, as the eigenvalues of $A^m=J-I$ are $n-1$ (simple eigenvalue) and $-1$ (with multiplicity $n-1$), the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\rho(A)=(n-1)^{1/m}$ and a number of $m$-th roots of $-1$. Hence $\rho(A)=|\det(A)|$ and in turn $\rho(A)$ is an integer.